# Como sería la prueba de escritorio de este algoritmo recursivo?

Tags: java, recursión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero saber como seria una prueba de escritorio con el #5, no entiendo muy bien el algoritmo.

Comment: No tengo idea de lo que es una prueba de escritorio. Pero lo que tienes ahí es una (sumatoria de números impares) +1, desde i=2 hasta n-1.  Es decir tienes n=5, entonces son los primero 4 impares y al final le sumamos 1 --> 3+5+7+9+1. Con n=2 -> 3+1. Aunque en una función recursiva realmente los número estarían invertidos, es decir la secuencia seria 9+7+5+3+1

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es un captura de pantalla de una tarea escolar. No hacemos tareas de la escuela en [es.so].